# How to set title for rectangular UIButton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

hi am new to iOS development and am trying to create Rectangular UIButton But button title is not visible. Below is my code... anybody can help me whats wrong in this code... thanks in advance...

```
_locationBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
CALayer *layer = [_locationBtn layer];
//[layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[layer setCornerRadius:0.0];
[layer setBorderWidth:1.0];
[layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor grayColor] CGColor]];

[_locationBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(dropDownMtd) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
_locationBtn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 170, 280, 40);
[_locationBtn setTitle:@"Select location" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:_locationBtn];
```

Comment: Try to set the color of the title of the button: `[_locationBtn setTitleColor:aColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]`,

Answer (score 0):

So the solution:
The issue seems to be with the button title color (which I presume was the same color as its background).
So, by setting the title color (`aColor`) different:

```
[_locationBtn setTitleColor:aColor forState:UIControlStateNormal]
```